# Split year from date column and create new column with year with awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a dataset in csv format like this (6000 rows):

```
Store,Date,Weekly_Sales,Holiday_Flag,Temperature,Fuel_Price,CPI,Unemployment
1,05-02-2010,1643690.9,0,42.31,2.572,211.0963582,8.106
1,12-02-2010,1641957.44,1,38.51,2.548,211.2421698,8.106
---
---
```

I would like to split the date column to create a new one just with the year. something like this:

```
Store,Date,Year,Weekly_Sales,Holiday_Flag,Temperature,Fuel_Price,CPI,Unemployment
1,05-02-2010,2010,1643690.9,0,42.31,2.572,211.0963582,8.106
1,12-02-2010,2010,1641957.44,1,38.51,2.548,211.2421698,8.106
```

I was trying to use this code but I don't know how to modify it to solve my problem:
[How to extract the year...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691591/splitting-a-string-column-date-time-into-date-time-in-csv-file)

Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: A solution that is not year 10000 safe: `perl -pe 's/-(\d{4}),/-$1,$1,/'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a proper `csv` parser, e.g. [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest):

```bsh
csvsql --query "select Store,Date,strftime('%Y', Date) as Year,Weekly_Sales,Holiday_Flag,Temperature,Fuel_Price,CPI,Unemployment  from data" data.csv
```

Output:

```
Store,Date,Year,Weekly_Sales,Holiday_Flag,Temperature,Fuel_Price,CPI,Unemployment
1,2010-05-02,2010,1643690.9,0,42.31,2.572,211.0963582,8.106
1,2010-12-02,2010,1641957.44,1,38.51,2.548,211.2421698,8.106
```

---

But if you want to do it with `awk`, this would do:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
  NR==1{$2="Date,Year"}
  NR>1 {sub(/[0-9]{4}/, "&,&", $2)}
1' data.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. What does number 1 mean at the end of the awk expression?

Comment: `1` means just `true`. It will trigger the default action, which is print the line.

Comment: Excellent,thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==1{gsub("Date","Date,year",$0)} NR>1 {$2=$2","substr($2,7,4)}1' filename

Store,Date,year,Weekly_Sales,Holiday_Flag,Temperature,Fuel_Price,CPI,Unemployment
1,05-02-2010,2010,1643690.9,0,42.31,2.572,211.0963582,8.106
1,12-02-2010,2010,1641957.44,1,38.51,2.548,211.2421698,8.106
```